# Black (1976) model: boundary conditions with non-convergence of spot and forward prices

Tags: black-scholes, futures

Let's suppose we have a futures contract F in a market where the relation

$$F(t,T)=S(t)e^{r(T−t)}$$
doesn't hold.

What are the the boundary conditions for the derivation of the Black (1976) formula??

Comment: @MattWolf: I probably mislead you with the title. Imagine we have convergence but $F(t,T)=S(t)\exp (r(T−t))$ does not hold. From what was told to me, we can still apply the Black model. Therefore, I want to know how can we specify yhe boundary conditions.

Comment: I see. But if we have the Black formula $C=\exp(-r(T-t))(FN(d_1)-KN(d_2))$, does this mean we are assuming the relation $F(t,T)=S(t)\exp(r(T−t))$ is verified? or can we get the exact same expression for C without using that relation?

Comment: @JoaoSerafim please use the math formatting feature of the site it really makes quesations and comments more readable.

Comment: @SRKX Ok. I will do that.

Comment: @MattWolf: I'm sorry but I'm getting a little bit confused. I'm going to reformulate my question. For example, in the context of stock markets, the price for an european call option on futures is given by the previous $C$ expression. Now let's imagine we are going to study another market and in this market the relation doesn't hold. Is it possible that the price of the options (in that new market) is still given by the exact $C$ expression?

Comment: @JoaoSerafim, I deleted my comments because I felt they were misleading. Quick summary of what I have been trying to say: The Black model is just the base framework. Depending on the underlying-forward/futures relationship (equity futures, commodity futures, currency futures, index f), the Black framework needs to be slightly adjusted and you end up with an extension of the Black framework, such as with Garman-Kohlhagen.

Comment: @MattWolf, I get it now. So, basically we can apply the Black model framewrok provided that we know the relationship between spot and forward prices that gives convergence, right??